# How to add label for each data from dataset in chartjs 2.9.4?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuPva.png)

Does anyone know how to add this label to chartjs 2.9.4?
I need to add label before each data

```
data: {
    labels: [
        "M01-Juil.",
        "M02-Août.",
        "M03-Sept.",
        "M04-Oct.",
        "M05-Nov",
        "M06-Déc.",
        "M07-Jan.",
        "M08-Juil.",
        "M09-Mars.",
        "M10-Avr.",
        "M11-Mai.",
        "M12-Juin",
    ],
    datasets: [{
        label: "2020-2021",
        data: [679850, 694802, 1053175, 661847, 649864, 496568, 545552, 1808332, 649864, 996568, 545552, 108332],
        backgroundColor: "#00a1e0",
    }, {    
        label: "2021-2022",
        data: [1349542, 634802, 1553175, 1661847, 149864, 296568, 345552, 808332, 649864, 926568, 2545552, 838332],
        backgroundColor: "#16325c",
    }, {
        label: "2022-2023",
        data: [1428664, 394802, 2053175, 3164986, 645864, 996568, 245552, 838332, 649864, 1996568, 545552, 208332],
        backgroundColor: "#76ded9",
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read about the `datalabels` plugin for `chart.js`? You can find more info [here](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/).

After importing that library, you can update your chart config as follows:

```
options: {
plugins: {
    datalabels: {
        align: 'end',
        anchor: 'end',
        color: 'black',
        formatter: function(value, context) {
            return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex] + ': ' + value;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The `formatter` attribute is the crucial part here.